# Push notifications not sending in production but work in sandbox - AWS SNS / APNS

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I have a new iOS app.  Certs all new, everything created from scratch.

I have created the SNS Platform Application for push.  Uploaded the newly created cert. All ok.

App user logs in, and the endpoint is created no problem.

As soon as a message is sent, it goes disabled.  The error message logged is:

```
\":\"Platform token associated with the endpoint is not valid\",\"FailureType\":\"InvalidPlatformToken\
```

I have recreated these certificates etc so many times now.  Tried everything, but just cant make this work.  Have tried manually via push try.com and using a local app, both of which report bad token.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Have tried new certs.  Deleted everything from my keychain, and reinstalled as newly generated and downloaded from AppstoreConnect.

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason is that you are not using the right device token for the generated ARN.
If its a production ARN, the device token is expected from a production app (testflight or appstore).
If its a sandbox ARN, the device token is expected from a debug build(Run from xcode).
If the above is not followed, SNS platform will disable the endpoint.

Hope this helps.